Flutter FadeInImage Test
I've been trying to write a simple test for FadeInImage but with no luck. I just want to test if kTransparentImage appears as a placeholder. Then after a certain wait time (default 700ms), the URL image appears and kTransparentImage disappears.
First we'll need to use an HttpClient in order to display network image. I use nock, but feel free to use your own.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Test FadeInImage', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
      placeholder: kTransparentImage,
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/28/200',
    ));

    // First: Solve for "provide your own HttpClient implementation" error

    // Second: Test for placeholder image (kTransparentImage)
    // expect placeholder image: findsOneWidget
    // expect network image: findsNothing

    // Third: Wait until network image to appear

    // Forth: Test for network image (https://picsum.photos/id/28/200)
    // expect placeholder image: findsNothing
    // expect network image: findsOneWidget
  });
}


this is how i managed to test this:
I am using the network_image_mock to mock network images.
Note: The Dart testing environment doesn't have a concept of real time, so the "wait time" of 700ms doesn't apply here. Instead, pumpAndSettle() is used to simulate the passage of time.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:network_image_mock/network_image_mock.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Test FadeInImage', (tester) async {
    mockNetworkImagesFor(() async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        home: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
          image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/28/200',
        ),
      ));

      // Test for placeholder image (kTransparentImage)
      expect(find.byType(FadeInImage), findsOneWidget);

      // Pump a new frame to start the image load
      await tester.pump();

      // Wait until network image to appear
      // Wait for the image to load
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // Test for network image (https://picsum.photos/id/28/200)
      final image = tester.widget<FadeInImage>(find.byType(FadeInImage));
      expect(
          (image.image as NetworkImage).url, 'https://picsum.photos/id/28/200');
    });
  });
}

Hope this helps:)

This test passes (even without the pump and pumpAndSettle) but it doesn't really test the flow, i.e. kTransparentImage should appear first then disappear and  NetworkImage shouldn' appear at first then should appear after pumping. I edited the question to address this point
